# Building Java package (javac to all files)

Tags: java, javac

How to compile all files in directory to *.class files?

Comment: 1) see makefile (or ant or maven or ....)
2) No

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, this seems pretty obvious, so I may be missing something

```
javac *.java
```

(With appropriate library references etc.)

Or perhaps:

```
javac -d bin *.java
```

to javac create the right directory structure for the output.

Were you looking for something more sophisticated? If so, could you give more details (and also which platform you're on)?

Comment: what about all java files in all sub and decending directories?

Comment: @Tom: Find that would depend on the operating system. It's dead easy on Unix, using find. Harder on Windows.

Comment: *so I may be missing something*: Yes, one should not be inside the package directory when compiling, since then classes not explicitely named on the command line can't be found (i.e. these in other packages and not included in the compiler's bootstrap path).  `javac super/package/dir/*.java` would be the right way to do it (maybe adding `-d`, `-cp`, and/or `-sourcepath`).

Comment: This is probably incomplete, because I get "`javac: file not found: *.java`" on Windows 7.

Comment: @TomášZato: That just means you haven't got any `.java` files in the current directory. It's hard to compile source code when there aren't any source files...

Comment: @JonSkeet the files were in subdirectories. I really expected `javac` to be able to find them recursively.

Comment: what if .java files are in different packages under `src` folder?

Comment: @UnKnown: Then you specify all the files in all the relevant directories.

Answer (score 10):

Yet another way using "find" on UNIX is described here:

http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2010/01/compile-recursively-with-javac.html

The following two commands will compile all .java files contained within the directory `./src` and its subdirectories:

```
find ./src -name *.java > sources_list.txt
javac -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" @sources_list.txt
```

First, `find` generates `sources_list.txt`, a file that contains the paths to the Java source files. Next, `javac` compiles all these sources using the syntax `@sources_list.txt`.

Comment: Consider improving your post since your answer is essentially a link. See: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/156620) and [Why is linking bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/156620)

Comment: Nice solution. You skip the temporary file by using /dev/stdin though. ie. `find ./src -name *.java | javac -classpath "${CLASSPATH}" @/dev/stdin`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code fragment that I use to build an entire project where, as usual, source files are in a deeply nested hierarchy and there are many .jar files that must go into the classpath (requires UNIX utilities):

```
CLASSPATH=
for x in $(find | grep jar$); do CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$x"; done
SRC=$(find | grep java$)
javac -cp "$CLASSPATH" $SRC
```