# Is it possible to compile the src directory in a single command?

Tags: opa

I would like to compile all the .opa files in my src directory in a single command without having to specify each file manually, or having to specify them manually in a config file.

This is the parrallel issue in Java: [Building Java package (javac to all files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356443/building-java-package-javac-to-all-files)
And here: [Compiling java files in all subfolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194926/compiling-java-files-in-all-subfolders)

Do I need to do something with the makefile?
Is there an Ant equivalent for Opa?

Answer (score 1):

`opa src/*.opa` should work ;)

Otherwise, it's just basic Makefile manipulation i guess.

Comment: I tried this, but it results in the following:

`Warning load-import
File "src/bootstrap.opa", line 2, characters 0-19, (2:0-2:19 | 27-46)
  Cannot find any package that matches the import myproject.view.
Hint:
  Perhaps you forgot to include some directories (-I option).
Error
Fatal warning: 'load-import'
`

It can't find it's dependencies in this way. The `make run` command in conjunction with the config file works fine however.

Answer (score 1):

Use `opa create` to generate example MVC application. It will contain basic `Makefile` and `opa.conf` files used to compile the whole project. `Makefile` contains commands to compile and run your project. Use command `make` see the result. File `opa.conf` describes dependencies between your `*.opa` files. Tool `make` allows to use filesystem wildcard and you should be able to change configuration files easily.

Take a look at the [blog post](http://blog.opalang.org/2012/06/programming-tools-ux-how-we-simplified.html) introducing the `opa create` and the `make` [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) (its long, because it has lots of features you probably wont need, but you may start with the examples)

Comment: That is what I currently use. However, describing the dependencies in a single file is something I am not looking forward to. I would like to state the package and import requirements on a per-file basis. I will look into make's wildcard option. Thanks.